# Recently started VerifyError with Cloudees build

Tags: cloudbees

mvn clean install works fine locally but when we run it with cloudbees, we are seeing build failures with the following exception (see below).

Anyone has a clue?

```
Exception in thread "pool-16-thread-3" Exception in thread "pool-17-thread-1" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/httpclient/auth/BasicUserPrincipal, method: implies signature: (Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials.<init>(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.openConnectionInternal(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection(AbstractWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:218)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.connectWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:345)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.pollWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:385)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:571)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/httpclient/auth/BasicUserPrincipal, method: implies signature: (Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials.<init>(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.openConnectionInternal(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection(AbstractWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:218)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.connectWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:345)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.pollWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:385)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:571)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception in thread "pool-19-thread-1" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/httpclient/auth/BasicUserPrincipal, method: implies signature: (Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials.<init>(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.openConnectionInternal(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection(AbstractWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:218)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.connectWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:345)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.pollWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:385)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:571)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception in thread "pool-16-thread-2" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/httpclient/auth/BasicUserPrincipal, method: implies signature: (Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials.<init>(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.openConnectionInternal(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection(AbstractWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:218)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.connectWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:345)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.pollWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:385)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:571)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Downloaded: http://repo.cloudbees.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (614 B at 4.2 KB/sec)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/httpclient/auth/BasicUserPrincipal, method: implies signature: (Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials.<init>(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.openConnectionInternal(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection(AbstractWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:218)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.connectWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:345)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.pollWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:385)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:571)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    ... 3 more
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:152)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:161)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/httpclient/auth/BasicUserPrincipal, method: implies signature: (Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials.<init>(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.openConnectionInternal(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection(AbstractWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:218)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.connectWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:345)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.pollWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:385)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:571)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your job configured to use OpenJDK 8 by any chance? This stack trace seems to appear when running Maven builds on JDK 8. It is still under investigation.

Comment: Yes, the job is configured with OpenJDK 8.